# Privacy and firefox's new "Share Services"

Tags: firefox

Firefox now has a special share button built in. I quite like this idea but I have a policy of not being signed in on social media sites as I browse (because of all the tracking via those companies' share buttons).

If I use firefox's share service, e.g. for twitter, does that mean I am logged in at twitter?

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't use this service if you have a policy not to use services like it.  If you provide your twitter authentication information at any point then your logged into Twitter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing I conclude that using this feature DOES sign you in in such a way that it is shared with web pages you visit, i.e. it adds a cookie to your browser.

Sign out of twitter. Try the share button, it asks you to sign in. Sign in inside the share button. Visit twitter - you're logged in again.

Pity, it would have been a nice feature if it kept a separate cookie and enabled me to share when I want to share but disallowed the constant leaching of personal information that you get from being logged in to social networks.

From https://blog.mozilla.org/privacy/2012/10/22/being-social-with-privacy-in-mind/

> They share cookies and other data like normal